# Possible to dismiss JS alerts automatically whenever an unhandled one appears?

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

The issue I'm running into is that sometimes JS dialogue behavior is unpredictable within the application being tested. I wish I could say I could do anything about it, but I can't because I am only experiencing this weird behavior with cucumber. Also, it's not of my concern to test the actual dialogue boxes. In other words, we just want to click through and dismiss them whenever they happen.

```
begin
    find('div', :text => 'Cancel').double_click # Click cancel
    accept_browser_dialog # We've got two dialogue boxes to click through
    accept_browser_dialog # That makes two.. but what if a third was created?
    # Wouldn't it be great if I could just dismiss them as they appeared?
rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError # <- SOMETHING LIKE THIS
    accept_browser_dialog # Handled easy as pie.. in theory
end # etc etc etc
```

See the line I marked above. Every time I click 'Cancel' there are two dialogues to click through, but sometimes the `double_click` call likes to bring up a third dialogue box. Rather than playing games with counting dialogues and the like, is there any way to simply dismiss them as they appear whenever an unhandled alert error happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the system modal boxes (alert, confirm, prompt) When using the selenium driver you can just try to accept an open alert and catch the error raised if one doesn't exist.

```
find('div', :text => 'Cancel').double_click # Click cancel
accept_browser_dialog # We've got two dialogue boxes to click through
accept_browser_dialog # That makes two.. but what if a third was created?
begin
  accept_alert(wait: 0.1)
rescue  Capybara::ModalNotFound
end
```

Comment: Works perfectly as usual Tom, thanks for your assistance. It came down to using accept_alert which gives us a nice exception to catch and try clicking the element again to prompt the dialogues to appear, and with a little tinkering with the wait and placement in the code it fixed the flickering scenarios.

Comment: @JTApps You're welcome -- Unfortunately (as stated) it isn't cross driver since it depends on the undocumented (but tested for) ability for accept_alert to work without a block that triggers the modal in the selenium driver.  Most other drivers need to know before a system modal is going to appear so they can catch it, hence the documented/usual `accept_alert { actions that trigger the alert }` syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you're doing, and **really** have to bypass all JavaScript alerts and dialogs regardless of the consequences, you could always [follow this advice](http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/):

```
driver.execute_script("window.alert = function() {}")
driver.execute_script("window.prompt = function() {return null}")
driver.execute_script("window.confirm = function() {return true}")
```

which is certainly cleaner than trying to deal with unpredictable, variable behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, I wish there was another option here but there really isn't. Where in the code library is this getting put?

Comment: Would have to be called after every page load, to be sure. But if you can narrow it down by page / dialog type, so much the better. Could / should also be combined into a single `execute_script` to reduce the number of round-trips.